# LG Gram Brightness changes when rebooting

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, intel-graphics, lg-gram

On a Windows 10 2019 LG Gram, the brightness changes when I load up media or site that changes a bunch of pixels.  The brightness still reports 100%, but the screen is noticeably brighter/dimmer (depending on the content displayed).

On a Windows 11 2021 LG Gram, the brightness changes shortly after reboot, but I can see the dimness reported in the slider and I can manually increase it back.

Windows Adaptive Display, Night Shift, Power Options display are all off.  How can I get the brightness to just stay at 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the 2019 Gram, the issue appears to be due to DPST -  Intel® Display Power Saving Technology.  This is not always changeable in the Intel Graphics Center, and this tool will change registry keys to disable it. https://github.com/orev/dpst-control  (Download the release zip on the side, and follow the Usage steps.  Requires Admin Access as it access Registry).  Thank you [Tom Scott](https://twitter.com/tomscott/status/1442153514357174273?lang=en) for randomly tweeting this.
2. For the 2021 Gram, I installed the above.  There seemed to be a secondary issue due to the LG bloatware. I think specifically LGDisplay On (or something to that effect).  In Task Manager > Startup, I disabled all LG software and the issue has dissapeared.
3. If this hasnt solved your issue, An available bandaid, assuming Windows knows the brightness is lower, is to save this a powershell script and put it in your startup folder.

```
Start-Sleep -s 15
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but the closest I found to my issue. I have a late 2022 14" Gram. lately it has been significantly lowering brightness after sleep. The issues:

1. This seems random. Always happens after laptop wakes up in the morning, whether it was plugged in or not.
2. The brightness slider remain where is should be, at 80. When moved up or down even by 1 click, the display immediately comes back to the desired brightness.

LG Display On and Glance both disables in Startup, however, LG Smart Assistant is running and I'm not sure how to disable that to test.

Any help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207556)